# alphanumeric regex javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am having a problem to get the simple reges for alphanumeric chars only work in javascript :

```
var validateCustomArea = function () {
        cString = customArea.val();
        var patt=/[0-9a-zA-Z]/;
        if(patt.test(cString)){
            console.log("valid");
        }else{
            console.log("invalid");
        }
    }
```

I am checking the text field value after keyup events from jquery but the results are not expected, I only want alphanumeric charachters to be in the string

Comment: Shouldn't there be a semicolon on your third line there?

Comment: code is running fine it is just the results are wrong

Comment: @Dan: Semicolons are, in fact, optional in JavaScript.

Comment: I am guessing the regex above checks if in your string exists any, I want for my string to be only alphanumeric

Comment: @muistooshort Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't they optional *most* of the time? Sometimes they are required, hence the good habit to always use them.

Comment: @Alien: Optional when there is no ambiguity and that's pretty much all the time. But leaving them out (except in things like `function() { return 11 }`) isn't a great idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it this way

```
var validateCustomArea = function () {
        cString = customArea.val();
        console.log(cString)
        var patt=/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/
        if(!cString.match(patt)){
            console.log("valid");
        }else{
            console.log("invalid");
        }
    }
```

I needed to negate the regex

Answer (score 7):

This regex:

```
/[0-9a-zA-Z]/
```

will match any string that contains at least one alphanumeric character. I think you're looking for this:

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/
/^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/ /* If you want to allow "empty" through */
```

Or possibly this:

```
var string = $.trim(customArea.val());
var patt   = /[^0-9a-z]/i;
if(patt.test(string))
    console.log('invalid');
else
    console.log('valid');
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function only checks one character (`/[0-9a-zA-Z]/` means *one* character within any of the ranges 0-9, a-z, or A-Z), but reads in the whole input field text.  You would need to either loop this or check all characters in the string by saying something like `/^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/`.  I suggest the latter.